# Recognising EOF File Character in Antlr3 Lexer

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to parse some strings using ANTLR 3...they are to be enclosed in single quotation marks. Therefore, if the user doesn't pass an even number of quotation marks it runs all the way to the end of file as it assumes it's a massive string.

Is there a way to specify ANTLR to recognize the EOF character? I've tried `'<EOF>'` and `'\\z'` to now avail.

Comment: `EOF` means end of file, not end of line. If you are trying to *prevent* ANTLR from reading to the end of the file, then `EOF` is definitely not what you're looking for because it specifically means you *want* it to read to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

To handle a single quoted string literal in ANTLR, you'd do something like this:

```
SingleQuotedString
  :  '\'' ('\\' ('\\' | '\'') | ~('\\' | '\'' | '\r' | '\n'))* '\''
  ;
```

meaning:

```
'\''                              # a single quote
(                                 # (
  '\\' ('\\' | '\'')              #   a backslash followed by \ or '
  |                               #   OR
  ~('\\' | '\'' | '\r' | '\n')    #   any char other than \, ', \r and \n
)*                                # ) zero or more times
'\''                              # a single quote
```

And to denote the end-of-file token inside ANTLR rules, simply use `EOF`:

```
parse
  :  SingleQuotedString+ EOF
  ;
```

which will match one or more `SingleQuotedString`s, followed by the end of the file (`EOF`). The char `'\z'` is not a valid escape char inside ANTLR rules.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `EOF` didn't work for me (am using antlr v4)
An alternative is to handle the `EOF` at a upper level. For example if you define `EOF` as statement separator this way:

```
program     : statement+ ;
statement   : some_stuff NEWLINE;
```

You could replace with:

```
program     : (statement NEWLINE)* statement? ;
statement   : some_stuff;
```

Comment: I think you are confusing `EOF` (end of file, and a predefined token in ANTLR) with EOL (end of line).